# Get all returning values from a transaction containing multiple queries - knex.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to update some rows at once.

I'm waiting for all queries to be written before executing them all in one query. However, I need some values to be returned by the query after the update. I'm using the `returning()` method for that.

I can't manage to get all the returned values at once as an array after the query has been executed. If I use a then() directly in the transaction function it returns the returned values one by one and my promise won't work. It also considerably increases the execution time.

How do I get all the returning values from my update request at once in a list.

```
return await knex.transaction(trx => {
        const queries = [];
        data.forEach(pair => {
            const query = knex('pair')
                .where('symbol', pair.s)
                .update({
                    last_price: pair.c,
                })
                .returning(['id'])
                .transacting(trx)
                //.then(function (updated) {
                // ... doing it one by one here
                //})
            queries.push(query);
        });

        return Promise.all(queries) // Once all queries are written
            .then(() => { 
                trx.commit // We try to execute them all

            .catch((e) => {
                trx.rollback // And rollback in case any of them goes wrong
                console.error(e)
            }); 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without using `trx.commit()`:

```
async function updateDB(data) {
    return await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
        const queries = [];

        data.forEach(item => {
            const query = knex('core_exchangepair')
                .where('symbol_slug', item.s)
                .transacting(trx) 
                .update({
                    last_price: item.c,
                })
                .returning(['id'])
            queries.push(query);
        });

        try {
            return await Promise.all(queries);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            return e;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Right. That's because this Promise.all() uses implicit return because it has no then().

Answer (score -1):

The await after the return is unnecessary. You need to await your Promise.all before returning it, so your trx function should be async.

Comment: ok but how do I get all returning values at once?

Comment: You need to return something from the then() in your promise.all(). Currently you return nothing.  Try something like: .then((results) => {trx.commit; return results;})